# Update request of the axios library

Tags: axios

I have an issue with update method of axios library in my front-end application react, I can't send an HTTP update request to an API (application Crud in Spring Boot)

1. link to UpdateUser.js component in the bottom

```
import UserService from '../services/UserService'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function UserComponent(){

    const [stateData, setState] = useState([])
    const[err,setError] = useState(false)
    
useEffect(()=>{
         try { 
            const api = UserService()   
            api.then(response=> setState(response.data))
           //axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users').then(response=> setState(response.data))
         } catch (error) {
             setError(true)
         }
      }, [])  

      
       function deleteUser(id) {
        return axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/delete/'+id);
      } 
 
   if(err){return <span>oups il y a une erreur!</span>}
 
    return(
            <div>
                <h1 className = "text-center"> Users List</h1>
                <table className = "table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <td> User Id</td>
                            <td> User First Name</td>
                            <td> User Last Name</td>
                            <td> User Email Id</td>
                            <td> Actions</td>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            stateData.map(
                                user => 
                                <tr key={user.id}>
                                     <td> {user.id}</td>   
                                     <td> {user.firstName}</td>   
                                     <td> {user.lastName}</td>   
                                     <td> {user.email}</td>
                                     <td> 
                                         <button onClick={()=>deleteUser(user.id)}>delete</button>
                                         <Link to="/update" params={{ id: user.id}}>update</Link>
                                     </td>     
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        )

}
export default UserComponent
```

2. my UpdateUser component which filtered a user with his id mentioned as a param and put it in the state that I will modify by values token in the form tag:

```
import React, { useParams, useState } from 'react';
import UserService from '../services/UserService'
import axios from'axios'

function UpdateUser(){

    const { id } = useParams()
    const [stateData, setState] = useState([])
           //const api = UserService()  
           axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users'+id, user).then(response=> {
               response.filter(user=> user.id==={id})
               setState(response.data)})

    function handle(e){
            stateData[e.target.id]= e.target.value
            setState(stateData)
                }

    function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/update/{',{
                    firstName: stateData.firstName,
                    lastName: stateData.lastName,
                    email: stateData.email,
                    }).then(res=> {console.log(res.data)})
                }        
                
     return(
         <div>
         <form onSubmit={(e)=>submit(e)}>
         <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id ="firstName" value={stateData.firstName} placeholder="firstName" type="text"></input>
         <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id ="lastName" value={stateData.lastName} placeholder="lastName" type="text"></input>
         <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id ="email" value={stateData.email} placeholder="email" type="email"></input>
         <button>submit</button>
          </form>
            <ul >
                <li> {stateData.id}</li>   
                <li> {stateData.firstName}</li>   
                <li> {stateData.lastName}</li>   
                <li> {stateData.email}</li>                     
            </ul>
            <button onClick={()=> updateUser()}>update</button>
             
         </div>
     )
}

export default UpdateUser
```

3. my racine file index.js, I think there is a problem in the route with path="/update"

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/Header'
import AddUser from './components/AddUser'
import Error from './components/Error'
import UpdateUser from './components/Error'
import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' ;
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<App />}>
              </Route> 
              <Route path="/add" element={<AddUser />}>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/update/:id" element={<UpdateUser />}>
              </Route>
              <Route  element={<Error />}>
              </Route>
              
              </Routes>
    </Router> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

4. my implementation of update method within controller class of back-end application Spring Boot

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public User updateEmployee(@RequestBody User user) {
        User u = new User();
        u = this.userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();
        u.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        u.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return this.userRepository.save(u);
    }

}
```

Comment: The port in the cross origin config is 3000 there but you're making the request to port 8080 ?

Comment: `axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/update/{'` has a trailing `{` in the url, is that just a typo in the code you posted or is that actually in your code?